# Decimal float number to Hexadecimal in Python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, number-systems

I am trying to convert a floating point number from decimal to hexadecimal.
But I am not getting in the format I want.
For example, if the decimal number is `54.75`, I want the hexadecimal in the format `36.C0`
However, I am not able to convert it to this format.

```
float.hex(54.75)
```

gives `0x1.b600000000000p+5`

Python built-in function `hex()` also doesn't support float numbers.

Comment: Split your decimal into its integer and fractional parts, convert each of those to hex, and combine for final results.

Comment: Are you suggesting using the custom function or using the Python built-in hex() function? @ScottHunter

Comment: I'm not suggesting any particular function; I'm suggesting a technique.

Comment: I have already written a custom function to convert it as stated above. But I was looking for a Pythonic way or built-in Python function to do it @ScottHunter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can split the number into various parts and then combine the converted results. For example:

```py
import math
import re


def get_hex(n):
    assert not math.isinf(n)
    assert not math.isnan(n)

    for sign, a, b in re.findall(r"(-?)(\d+)\.?(\d*)", str(n)):
        if b:
            return f"{sign}{int(a):X}.{int(256 * float('0.' + b)):>02X}"
        else:
            return f"{sign}{int(a):X}"


print(get_hex(54.05))
print(get_hex(54.50))
print(get_hex(54.75))
print(get_hex(15))
print(get_hex(-15))
print(get_hex(-15.21))
print(get_hex(100_000_000_000.15))
```

Prints:

```
36.0C
36.80
36.C0
F
-F
-F.35
174876E800.26
```

Comment: I already tried something like this. But as you can see, the output for `54.75` is `36.4B` in your program, but the expected output is `36.C0` @Andrej

Comment: @ksohan Can you explain why `C0` and not `4B` ?

Comment: `print(get_hex(54.05))` and `print(get_hex(54.50))` both print `36.5`.  I would not expect the same for both inputs is acceptable and for the 2nd I'd  `36.8` to meet OP's goal.

Comment: @ksohan I've updated my answer... I hope I've understood it right this time.